# How to handle attribute directive output event in angular

Tags: angular

I want to have control over the directive when it fires I am showing a suitable message on the screen other than showing error message,  Can you please let me know how can this event be captured,I am using a attribute directive in this case. Please help.

duplicate-title.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[duplicateTitle]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DuplicateTitleDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class DuplicateTitleDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('duplicateTitle') duplicateTitle:Object;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private vueTranslationService: VueTranslationService){}

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.isDuplicateTitleExist(this.duplicateTitle['ds'], (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value,this.duplicateTitle['id']) ?{vueCustomValidation: this.getTranslation('error.duplicateTitle')}:null ;
  }

private isDuplicateTitleExist(node,title,id):boolean{
  
  if(node && node.sectionTitle === title && node.id !== id){
   return true;
 }
 if(node && node.subExamSections){
     for(let i=0 ;i< node.subExamSections.length;i++){
        return this.isDuplicateTitleExist(node.subExamSections[i],title,id)
     }
 }
}

public getTranslation(key: string): string | null {
  return this.vueTranslationService.getTranslation('ClientPublishing', key);
}

}
```

my html file looks like this

```
  <vue-control-group class="width-30pc" label="Title*" srLabel="srtest" [formError]="formError" [control]="title"
    excludeValidationMessage="true">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="inpt-width100pc" autofocus name="title" required vueMaxLength="250"
      [duplicateTitle]="{ds:dataSource.data[0],id:selectednode.id}" #title="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="selectednode.sectionTitle" id="title" aria-required="true">
    <vue-validation-message  i18nBundle="ClientPublishing" required="error.requiredTitle"
      vueValidateLength="error.maxErrorTitle" vueCustomValidation="error.requiredTitle" [control]="title"
      [formError]="formError"></vue-validation-message>
  </vue-control-group>
  <vue-control-group class="width-30pc" label="How should the content within this section be ordered?* "
    [formError]="formError" [control]="sectionorder" excludeValidationMessage="true">
   
     <select class="inpt-width100pc" id="sectionorder" name="sectionorder" #sectionorder="ngModel" [selectOption]=""
    [(ngModel)]="selectednode.sectionOrder" (ngModelChange)="sectionOrderChanged($event)"  >
    <option *ngFor="let sectionOrder of sectionOrders;"   >
               {{sectionOrder}} 
    </option>
  </select> 
  

    <vue-validation-message i18nBundle="ClientPublishing" vueCustomValidation [control]="sectionorder"
      [formError]="formError"></vue-validation-message>

  </vue-control-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue using the directive as below

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[duplicateTitle]',
  outputs: [ 'dupTitleErrMsg' ],
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DuplicateTitleDirective, multi: true}]
})
```

With the event emitter in the directive and the parent node which holds the directive to capture the event handler.